# Angular 2+ doesn't change a layout on page change

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

Here is my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'authorization',
component: AuthorizationLayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: AuthorizationLoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'advertiser',
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new-campaign',
        component: AdvertiserNewCampaignComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
{
path: 'advertiser',
canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard],
component: HomeLayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: AdvertiserDashboardComponent,
  },
}
```

Currently user is located on the page: /advertiser/dashboard. He wants to go to the page /authorization/advertiser/new-campaign. So he clicks on a link with routerLink="/authorization/advertiser/new-campaign" and it successfully moving him to this page. But for some reasons layout AuthorizationLayoutComponent doesn't load, only page itself. Why?

Comment: is `AdvertiserNewCampaignComponent` loading? can you post its @Component part?

Comment: Yes, the component of the page is loading (console.log prints message) and even component of the layout is loading. But html loads only from the page (no layout). It's weird because if I refresh the page, everything works fine

Comment: sorry i can't understand what's the meaning of `html loads only from the page (no layout).`

Comment: Sorry for my English. 
There is a layout (header, footer, etc.) and the page itself (form with inputs and submit button). But after user moved to this page there is only form without header and footer, even if console.log() displays a message from constructor.

Comment: Did you include a `<router-outlet>` element in the parent page?

Comment: Yes, but you pushed me on one idea. Layout just didn't load elements because of data that overrides in dashboard and then when user goes to new campaign the data already is not correct. I'm stupid didn't mention it. Anyway, thank you for help. I think I can close this question.